# JS: Algorithm to group dates by years and months in a tree

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree

I have a list of dates like this:

```
2019-12-15
2020-01-15
2020-01-23
```

I want to present them in a tree like so:

```
2019
  |__12
     |__15
2020
  |__01
     |__15
     |__23
```

is there an algorithm that can help achieve this with a good performance ? because the list of dates can get bigger and I'm afraid to face slow parsing algorithm.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your [mcve]? Are the date already ordered?

Comment: @aloisdgmovingtocodidact.com actually nothing, I was thinking about doing loops and stuff like that (traditional way) but I wanted to get new ideas about this.

Comment: What do you want to do about duplicate dates?

Comment: @SlimenTN write basic code. Write tests. Mesure time with huge case. Is the loop your bottleneck? Yes? Alright. Look to improve it.

Comment: @aloisdgmovingtocodidact.com yeah you're right about that I will try to do so, thanks :)

Comment: @Jacob duplicated dates must be removed I can use `Set` for that not a problem, but I want to know an algorithm that can help me achieve my goal with a better performance.

Comment: @SlimenTN With a for loop, your worst case is O(n). It is acceptable enough to run with that until it starts being a real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object and get the parts for nested objects by checking the property and take this property or add a new object as property.

```js
var data = ['2019-12-15', '2020-01-15', '2020-01-23'],
    tree = data.reduce((t, s) => {
        s.split('-').reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, t);
        return t;
    }, {});

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A fast approach.

```js
var data = ['2019-12-15', '2020-01-15', '2020-01-23'],
    tree = {};

for (const date of data) {
    let temp = tree;
    for (const key of date.split('-')) {
        if (!temp[key]) temp[key] = {};
        temp = temp[key];
    }
}

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, but am I gonna face performance problems when the dates list gets bigger ?

Comment: not sure, I'm gonna use this inside an application that can get bigger by days

Comment: so I assume that using `for` is better than `reduce` ?

Comment: it is faster and has no overhead.